# How to get processor code name

Tags: .net, cpu, information-retrieval, processor

I want to get processor **code name** (eg. "*Ivy Bridge*", "*Sandy Bridge*") like [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) tool on Windows but from C# code.

Comment: I am pretty sure CPU-Z has a built in lookup table that goes from model numbers to code names.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER` environment variable:

```
var cpuId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER");
```

In my case it prints:

```
// Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
```

WMI is also another method to get to the same information but this one is simpler.

Bear in mind, you may never be able to get the exact string CPU-Z provides since it is very likely it has a mapping table that reads this environment variable and internally maps to the *code name* and outputs.

Comment: Yes I already using WMI Win32_Processor class to get many others CPU properties I need, but code name is not there. So I can get Model, Stepping etc. The question is whether this table is available somewhere?